# Border land and polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

There are two countries that share a land border.

How do I make polygons based on the border without "drawing" the border for both countries- and thus having two borders instead of one?

I'm using ArcMap.

I've tried the clip tool , but it doesn't work for this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.  Since different software platforms are different, tagging the Question with two platforms is, in effect, asking two questions, and therefore likely to be closed.  Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one platform, and what you have attempted, and what problem you encountered.

Comment: You have tags for QGIS and ArcMap but do not tell us which particular software you wish to ask about in the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, polygons were constructed from a  directional list of arc segments, but whole rings perform better for most tasks. The [Polygon to Line tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/polygon-to-line.htm) can be used to generate a linestring feature class from polygon boundaries for render optimization.

The principal issue with polygon-to-line conversion is that the polygon topology must be as clean as possible, with "mutually exclusive and exhaustively complete" polygon rings. Placing the root polygon feature class in a feature dataset, then building a topology can be used to identify and repair sliver polygons in the gaps and overlaps between polygons as in your example.
It's also possible to use Integrate to clean slivers, but automated conflation tools can also collapse necessary polygons and shift boundaries (with respect to other layers) if the tolerance is too large. I've found it useful to use Repair Geometry frequently, to make sure that the polygon feature class doesn't pick up topology issues during the arc deconfliction process.

It is often useful, after generating these lines, to intersect them with a fishnet, then Dissolve on line class and fishnet-id, to make multipart lines which render very quickly by tile. I was able to improve the country boundary map service render time for random maps across Eurasia from 35 seconds to <100 milliseconds by drawing the admin1 and admin0 boundaries as optimal segment clusters instead of polygon outlines that included Russia and China.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I understand the polygon to line tool but did not understood how to use the other tools you mentioned - intersect and fishnet, and how it works for the task. Thanks (::